# How to make a chart for 2 columns containing same text values but not ordered the same?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 4 columns. 2 contain same text values but the order is not the same. The other two contains numerical values.

How I can compare the columns in charts (if the textual values not in the same order)?

Comment: from your description, the numerical columns are not relevant ... just sort the two text columns independently and compare them